# AngularJS, using ng-class to assign a class if variable = something

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to assign a different class to an icon if its category is selected. I want to add class ìcon-pfeil_unten` if variable category == a number. I am trying with:

```
<i class="icon-pfeil_oben" ng-class="{'icon-pfeil_unten': category.16}"></i>
```

Where 16 is the category's ID. If category == 16, nothing happens. I guess I am writing the expression wrong. What's the correct way to test the value of a variable using ng-class ?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can do:

```
ng-class="{true: 'icon-pfeil_unten', false: 'icon-pfeil-oben'}[category == 16]"
```

So basically, `if category == 16` evals to `true`, add class `icon-pfeil_unten`

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to toggle between two classes using a statement like this, e.g "if category == 16, add class icon-pfeil_unten, otherwise add class icon-pfeil_oben", or is there a better way to do that?

Comment: @Ali -- Yeah, I edited the answer, I believe that should work.

Comment: Worked like a charm, once I removed the initial class="" tag. Doesn't work if I leave that in. So the complete working element is: 
<i aria-hidden="true" ng-class="{true: 'icon-pfeil_unten', false: 'icon-pfeil_oben'}[category == 16]"></i>

Comment: @tymeJV Just curious, What if more than 1 class is to be made true (I mean activated) on the condition? What is the syntax for doing that? Thanks.

Comment: @Dravidian - I assume just add another class for the `true` condition, IE: `ng-class="{true: 'icon-pfeil_unten and_another_class' ..`

Comment: @tymeJV I also wanted to ask you, What if there are 2 conditions that i need to check for 2 different CSS classes on the same html element, Ex: `ng-class="{true: 'icon-pfeil_unten'}[category == 16], {true: 'blah-blah'}[something == true]"` 
Tried this but didn't work. Thank you!

Comment: @Dravidian - You can use this syntax: `ng-class="{'my-class-1' : condition, 'my-class-2' : condition }"`

Answer (score 22):

You can also do this short hand:

```
    ng-class="category==16 ? 'icon-pfeil_unten' : 'icon-pfeil-oben'"
```